# Storing 2D array in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a project for which I need to store data to the MySQL Database. 
For each activity, I can have several resources. Like for Activity One, I can have Resource1, Resource2, Resource3, etc.

How do I store these resources in one single column in the database?

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$value){
        //what do I insert?
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO activity
            (`serial`,`Name`) VALUES(null,'$value')");
    }
```

Right now, I'm just able to save the names of activities.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't; instead create an `activity_resources` table. That table can allow multiple rows to reference the same activity, and use each row to store a separate resource.

```
activity:
- identifier field (often an auto-increment, but perhaps "serial" in this case)
- fields for "fixed" activity data, such as: name, perhaps date started;
  basically any values all activities are expected to have in fixed quantities.

activity_resources:
- activity identifier
- resource value|data
```

If resources can be shared among multiple activities, instead have a `resources` table (that holds resources), and use the `activity_resources` table to for an M:N relationship; in this case, the table's rows will instead reference activity AND resource tables.

```
activity:
- identifier field (often an auto-increment, but perhaps "serial" in this case)
- fields for "fixed" activity data, such as: name, perhaps date started;
  basically any values all activities are expected to have in fixed quantities.

resource:
- identifier field
- resource value|data

activity_resources:
- activity identifier
- resource identifier
```